# Possible to write to BIOS from linux kernel mode?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Is it possible to flash/write to a `BIOS` from kernel mode in `Linux`?

I've been doing some research on this and can't find a definitive answer to this. I'm not so great with kernel level stuff and hardware.

From what I've been able to find, I know certain kernel facilities can interrogate the BIOS (see `dmidecode`) given the BIOS supports certain interfaces.

I know the difference between real and protected mode. But switching to real mode from Linux seems impossible to do (?). I also know `x86` has emulation for 8088 programs but unsure whether the emulation would allow flashing the BIOS.

Wouldn't it be possible to just write to certain addresses in kernel mode to "flash" the BIOS?

---

**Update** Working from the answer and comments below it seems the answer is yes depending on the hardware platform. The only, and necessary requirement is that the BIOS flash chip is addressable in the IO address space. You also need software support  fir flashing chips, whether kernel or user space. For example I found the user space utility `flashrom` that can do it on what seems to be a narrow set of hardware platforms.

Comment: instead of writing a para, you can mention in distinct lines

Comment: Sorry what are you saying?

Comment: Which BIOS, what platform ?

Comment: @stdcall; Any BIOS, x86 In general. If it is platform dependent, what platforms support it, which don't and how and why?

Comment: The BIOS is not x86 generic, it's specific to mother board manufactor there are several, AMIBIOS, SeaBIOS, etc.

Comment: @stdcall yeah I ~know. I'm a little in the dark about it all, but most modern BIOSes would support certain standard ABIs. SMBIOS for example. If there are cans and cants I would love to know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that if BIOS flash chip is connected to the IO address bus and you have all necessary drivers.

Comment: Thank you. Do you possibly have a link to any articles about it at all?

Comment: That's totally irrelevant.

Comment: @stdcall what is totally irrelevant?

Comment: If there's a way to flash the BIOS you can do it from the kernel. That's it. why the SPI interface is relevant here ? it can be I2C, 1Wire, Shared memory, the interface is not relevant.

Comment: @stdcall I know for sure about SPI and I didn't hear there is another IO connection that is more or less widespread.